# How to set/get ROS2 params from another node using Python?

Tags: ros, ros2, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

how can I get/set the parameter value of another node?

Something like

```
ros2 param get /my_node my_param
```

But in code?
Thank you all!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397679/how-to-set/get-ros2-params-from-another-node-using-python?/) by [MLEV](https://answers.ros.org/users/89654/mlev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2022-03-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/2415#issuecomment-1028468173

Ask and ye shall receive

class SetExternalParam(Node):

```
def __init__(self, server_name):
    super().__init__('nav2_simple_commander_parameter_setter')

    self.cli = self.create_client(SetParameters, '/' + server_name + '/set_parameters')
    while not self.cli.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=1.0):
        self.get_logger().info('service not available, waiting again...')
    self.req = SetParameters.Request()

def send_request(self, param_name, param_value):
    if isinstance(param_value, float):
        val = ParameterValue(double_value=param_value, type=ParameterType.PARAMETER_DOUBLE)
    elif isinstance(param_value, int):
        val = ParameterValue(integer_value=param_value, type=ParameterType.PARAMETER_INTEGER)
    elif isinstance(param_value, str):
        val = ParameterValue(string_value=param_value, type=ParameterType.PARAMETER_STRING)
    elif isinstance(param_value, bool):
        val = ParameterValue(bool_value=param_value, type=ParameterType.PARAMETER_BOOL)
    self.req.parameters = [Parameter(name=param_name, value=val)]
    self.future = self.cli.call_async(self.req)
    while rclpy.ok():
        rclpy.spin_once(self)
        if self.future.done():
            try:
                response = self.future.result()
                if response[0].successful:
                    return True
            except Exception as e:
                pass
            return False
```

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MLEV](https://answers.ros.org/users/89654/mlev/) on 2022-03-18**:
Thank you, I'll try it